# Dose anybody know how to make area of triangle in python, using acos. I know to vektors and have length of them

Tags: python

```
import math
from pylab import *

x1 = int(input("x1 til første vektor"))
y1 = int(input("y1 til første vektor"))

u = array([x1, y1])

print(u)


x2 = int(input("x2 til andre vektor"))
y2 = int(input("y2 til andre vektor"))


v = array([x2, y2])
print(v)

l1 = float(sqrt(x1**2+y1**2))
print (l1)

l2 = float(sqrt(x2**2+y2**2))
print (l2)
```

Comment: what's your question? are you asking about the math or the programming?

Comment: I am asking about program, cuz i don't know how to use cosine in python

Comment: Here is a [link to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions). One key to remember, is these functions work in *rads*; input and output. These [two methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#angular-conversion) can be used for quick conversion if you like.

Answer (score 0):

It is a math question. You do not need acos here, because you would only need the angle to take back its cosinus. The fact is that the area or the area of the parallelogram generated by 2 vectors is their vector product (or more exactly its absolute value). If you want the area of the triangle, it is half the area of the parallelogram.

So what you need is:

```
area = abs(x1 * y2 - x2 * y1) / 2
```